# erro ao usar @media

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

A página é essa:

http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/admin

o `css` é esse:

```
    ...
media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:480px)  {

.sessoes {  
    width:100%;
}

.menu {
    background:none;
}

  .menus {
      width:100%;
  }

  .menusItens {
      display:inline;
   }

   ul.listaTopo {
      display:block;
   }

   ul li.listaLi {
      clear:both;
      display:inline-block;
   }

   ul li.listaLi a{
      display:inline-block;
   }

    .final, .base {
        width:100%;
        font-size:10px;
    }

.final {
    height:80px;
}

    .baseEsquerda, .baseDireita {
        width:45%;
    }

    .finalEsquerda, .finalDireita {
        width:95%;
    }

}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:320px)  {  

  .formLogin {
     width: 300px;
  }

}
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:480px)  {

  .formLogin {
     width: 430px;
  }

}
```

Só esta dando certo o `@media` em `320px.`

Ou seja, se eu colocar tudo dentro do bloco

```
media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:320px)  {
}
```

Tem muita coisa ai que serve tanto para resolução de `320px` quanto para `480px` como por exemplo:

```
.sessoes {  
    width:100%;
}
```

Mas se eu faço

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:480px)  {

.sessoes {  
    width:100%;
}
...
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:320px)  {  
  .formLogin {
     width: 300px;
  }
 ... 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:480px)  {
  .formLogin {
     width: 430px;
  }
 ... 
}
```

Então em qualquer resolução (inclusive a de `320px` que estava funcionando) ele se comporta como se não estiver dentro de um bloco `@media` em qualquer resolução.

Onde estou errando?

Observei que o erro só acontece do cabeçalho para baixo.

Answer (score 1):

1) Você não precisa de um `"min-width: 0px"` se você já está dizendo que seu `"max-width"` é `320px`. O `CSS` vai servir pra qualquer dispositivo que tenha até `320px`.

2) Você tem um media query que vai de `320px a 480px`, portanto, tudo o que estiver dentro desse query irá sobrescrever o que estiver dentro da sua query com `max-width de 320px`, já que ambas tem o mesmo valor. O correto é que você faça uma query de:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:480px)  {
  {...}
}
```

Comment: Não resolveu. Mas o problema não era esse, uma vez que no ambiente normal (sem ser o admin) faço o mesmo e o erro não ocorre!  Mas de qualquer maneira já corrigi isso!

Comment: Sugiro então postar aqui como resolveu.

Comment: rrsr. Não consegui ainda. O que eu corrigi foi o lance de usar as li's como seletores conforme foi orientado. Mas o problema continua. Em http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/ faço o lance da interpolação dos @media queries e não deu problema. Mas em http://www.dinamicaimoveis.com.br/novo/admin não esta dando certo